# How to disable deserialization process of data at separate docker Hazelcast nodes (main nodes embedded within app)

Tags: java, serialization, docker-swarm, hazelcast

Hello and thanks in advance!

#### Question In short:

When using custom single serializer for all project's models for application with embedded Hazelcast, How to use "hazelcast/hazelcast" docker image without setting up this global serializer for "hazelcast/hazelcast"?  Or reason why there is no way.

#### More:

I am going to use the "hazelcast/hazelcast" docker image in Docker Swarm solely to be able to not lose data when restarting all applications with hazelcast embedded. For all other cases, the instance built into the application is used. So, all direct communication with hazelcast's data take place only through Hazelcast instance embedded into the application.

I use ReplicatedMap and ISet structures.
For ReplicatedMap I have set "in-memory-format: BINARY".
Also I set custom global serializer only for applications - I need one serializer for all my project types with my custom logic for determining actual *.class to de-serialize in.

I see the following error in the "hazelcast/hazelcast" container logs:

```
2020-11-03 00:41:50,180 [ERROR] [hz.pedantic_maxwell.partition-operation.thread-4] [c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl]: [192.168.1.103]:5700 [dev] [4.0.3] There is no suitable de-serializer for type 1. This exception is likely caused by differences in the serialization configuration between members or between clients and members.
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable de-serializer for type 1. This exception is likely caused by differences in the serialization configuration between members or between clients and members.
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.newHazelcastSerializationException(AbstractSerializationService.java:254) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:280) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:567) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.IOUtil.readObject(IOUtil.java:141) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.replicatedmap.impl.operation.VersionResponsePair.readData(VersionResponsePair.java:58) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.replicatedmap.impl.operation.ReplicateUpdateOperation.readInternal(ReplicateUpdateOperation.java:109) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.readData(Operation.java:750) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:203) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:339) ~[hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:407) [hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:166) [hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:136) [hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:123) [hazelcast-all-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
```

But I cannot figure out the reason. All nodes are members and only application embedded Hazelcast nodes writing and fetching data from ReplicatedMap and ISet.
I also tried set following setting:

```
hazelcast:
  serialization:
    check-class-def-errors: false
```

So, I expecting that there is no reason for data de-serialization within "hazelcast/hazelcast" docker nodes. Where am I wrong?

ALSO at my custom serializer logs I was surprized to see "HazelcastException.class, ClusterState.class, IllegalArgumentException.class" types. I trying to fix it adding custom serializer's for this types using hazelcasts's 'JavaDefaultSerializers.JavaSerializer.class'.
Somewhere along this step, I thought I was doing something wrong... :)
The last types I added were IllegalArgumentException and Exception finally. Waiting now for results...

Perhaps I'm missing some setting. But if possible, I would like to do without creating my own docker image and setting up a global deserializer for it if possible. Or at least figure out why it's impossible.

If it helps, May be I can do without an ISet. But of course it would be better to be able to use it.

Using ReplicatedMap is the reason for using Hazelcast.
I try it for speed up the response of the 'user_api' like services, when there are several separate services in the docker swarm that write data there and whole actual data can be stored within one machine (~1-2GB).

#### UPDATE 04.11.20 21:48:

I tested locally case when app (with embedded Hazelcast) started twice and one separate Hazelcast. And now seems like all works well. So, finally types I caught at de-serialization: `PartitionMigratingException, CallerNotMemberException, RetryableHazelcastException, WrongTargetException and ClusterState`

Seems like specifying custom serializer for types `Exception.class and ClusterState.class` using hazelcasts's `JavaDefaultSerializers.JavaSerializer.class` solves the problem. But it is about strange especially for `ClusterState.class` case.

The last is simple `enum` and it signals that I eventually need add all classes from 'com.hazelcast' to avoid serialization problems...

#### And may be answer on my question:

When using separate Hazelcast instances solely to be able to not lose data when restarting all applications with hazelcast embedded. And when global deserializer used for all project types at app side, you need:

1. `hazelcast.serialization.check-class-def-errors: false` at least for not embedded Hazelcast
2. Make sure all structures setting with `in-memory-format: BINARY`
3. At app side you need add custom deserializer using `JavaDefaultSerializers.JavaSerializer.class` for Exception.class and other types from package 'com.hazelcast'

I will update the information after using it for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deserialisation on app will happen regardless of whether its embedded or client/server. Reason - data that is stored on Hazelcast servers is not meant for local app instance only but is for any application that connects to this cluster. Embedded mode is just another way to talk to the cluster, it does not affect how your data operations will be performed; unless you have manually configured in-memory-format to something else, which would again be applied on all servers.

Side note: you can also connect an app with suitable client library using client APIs to connect and communicate with an embedded mode cluster.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that now it is obvious to me :) After further investigations I found problem I faced. There is communication between Hazelcast members and deserialization occurs even within not embedded Hazelcast and some of messages don't implements interfaces like `Portable` or `DataSerializable`. Example of these types are `Exception` and `ClusterState`. So, we see 'There is no suitable de-serializer for type 1' error here (that points for typeId of my custom global serializer).

Answer (score 0):

Serialization/Deserialization is part of process of storing and retrieving data from a distributed system. When the data is written to any data structure with default configurations, the data is serialized. When the data is queried, it is deserialized on application side. And this happens regardless of deployment strategy - client/server or embedded into application, Docker or no Docker.

To fix the exception, you need to place the class definition of your domain objects or objects that are being written on servers, on servers' as well as applications' classpath.

Note: if you were using IMap then you have the option of storing data in deserialized form on servers, for faster compute or predicate/queries execution, but that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand. I think I forgot to point: I configured ReplicatedMap to store bytes by "in-memory-format: BINARY". As you noticed, data deserializes on app side. So, I still do not see the reason why the not embedded Hazelcast (separate default docker image "hazelcast/hazelcast") should do deserialization. It receives/sends data only during synchronization/repartition between Hazelcast cluster. On app with embedded Hazelcast (that also member, not client) simple put/get operations are performed. No errors if I use only apps. Errors only at "hazelcast/hazelcast".